# "You have" idiom explanation

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms

From an interview (doesn't matter with whom):

> ...unfortunately, we have a nuclear world now. And **you have**,
>   Pakistan has them. **You have**, probably, North Korea has them

What is the meaning of the phrase "you have"? Is it like "look, here you are"?

Comment: It is an interjection which is used to enumerate similar examples.

Comment: It's hard to say with this little context. The speaker may simply have made a couple of false starts. Alternatively, the transcriber may have ignored gestures made by the speaker.

Comment: 'Them' being nuclear weapons / missiles, this is probably a deleted version of "And **you** have them ... **Pakistan** has them. _You_ have them; probably, **North Korea** has them."

Comment: I read this as "you have" = "you have the situation where/you have a world where"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the comment by John Feltz beneath the original question is exactly on point:

> I read this as "you have" = "you have the situation where/you have a world where"

In other words, the speaker has omitted words that would have made the sense of the sentence more immediately coherent. Following John Feltz's lead, we may conclude that the intended fuller wording of the quote would have been something like this:

> ...unfortunately, we have a nuclear world now. And you [now] have [a situation where] Pakistan has [nuclear weapons]. You [now] have [a situation where], probably, North Korea has them.

Such elided language is so common in speech (certainly in English and, I imagine, in most other languages) that listeners adjust their interpretation of the sentences' meaning to accommodate the incomplete wording. More often than not, we do this by treating vestigial phrases (such as, "you have" in this instance) as a false start, rather than as a marker for a longer phrase, and by cutting those words as well. That is, a listener is more likely to receive the interviewee's statement as

> ...unfortunately, we have a nuclear world now. And Pakistan [now] has [nuclear weapons]. [And] probably, North Korea [now] has them.

than as

> ...unfortunately, we have a nuclear world now. And you [now] have [a situation where] Pakistan has [nuclear weapons]. You [now] have [a situation where], probably, North Korea has them.

even though, in this instance, the speaker's repetition of "you have"—if it is not merely a verbal tic—indicates that the speaker means to frame the examples of the relatively new nuclear capabilities of Pakistan and North Korea as the kinds of things you have when you have a nuclear world. AS for who "you" is in the transcribed remarks, it is surely "all of us living in the world now."

In the real world, hearers don't have time to work out in detail what particular words a speaker has omitted and to nail down what all of the pronouns refer to, but in reviewing a transcript, we do—and that gives us the opportunity to interpolate probable missing elements into the recorded speech rather than simply pruning the utterance further to dispense with incomplete phrases.

The danger of such an undertaking, obviously, is that we may not agree about what, if anything is missing. That point is illustrated very nicely by the fact that commenters beneath the original question above have suggested four competing theories of how to interpret the posted sliver of transcribed speech.